# error handling within std::tranform iteration

Tags: c++, templates

This question is about customisation for handling errors within `std::transform`'s UnaryPredicate.

```
Parameters
first1, last1   -   the first range of elements to transform
first2  -   the beginning of the second range of elements to transform
d_first -   the beginning of the destination range, may be equal to first1 or first2
policy  -   the execution policy to use. See execution policy for details.
unary_op    -   unary operation function object that will be applied.
```

The standard API allows to customize a transformation logic that is happening during a single iteration. However, it is not documented how one could customise the behavior for outputing the result. Except for the requirement that `d_first` must be an input iterator. As a result `std::transform` performs 1 to 1 transformation by default. That means, thath the output range is of the same size as the input range.

However, I want to customize the behavior to *ignore* the output when an error has occurred. That would result in an output range of size `n_original - n_errors`.

Here is a code example, that parses a Visual Studio solution file string and gets a list of projects using regex. It is obvious, that the file can be corrupted to some extent, but failing on a step of extracting projects' info is not feasible - logging an error would suffice.

```
class VSParser
{
public:
    static auto projects(std::string_view slnFile)
    {
        std::regex pattern{
            R"(Project\(\"\{(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|\-){36}\}\"\)\s*=\s*\"(.+?)\",\s*\"(.+?)\",)"
        };

        struct ProjInfo
        {
            std::string name;
            std::filesystem::path path;
        };

        using regex_iter_type = std::regex_iterator<std::decay_t<decltype(slnFile)>::iterator>;

        std::vector<ProjInfo> projects;
        std::transform(regex_iter_type(slnFile.cbegin(), slnFile.cend(), pattern),
                       regex_iter_type(),
                       std::back_inserter(projects),
                       [](const auto &match) -> ProjInfo
                       {
                           // TODO: handle parsing errors
                           return {std::string(match[1]),
                           std::string(match[2])};
                       });

        return projects;
    }

private:
};
```

The problem here is that the `Ret` type of the `UnaryPredicate` must be the same as the type resulting from dereferencing the `OutputIter`. So I can't see how I could manage to compile the `UnaryPredicate` with `std::optional` as a return type:

```
        std::vector<ProjInfo> projects;
        std::transform(regex_iter_type(slnFile.cbegin(), slnFile.cend(), pattern),
                       regex_iter_type(),
                       [&projects](const auto&)
                       {
                         // insert if not nullopt
                       }, // example. Will not compile since an it is a callble, not
                       [](const auto &match) -> std::optional<ProjInfo> 
                       {
                           // TODO: handle parsing errors
                           return ProjInfo{std::string(match[1]),
                           std::string(match[2])};
                       });

        return projects;
```

I know that I can do a vector of optionals and then strip it from invalid elements, but since `std::optional<ProjInfo>` and `ProjInfo` are different types, it will double the allocation and copy overhead which I don't want if can be avoided.

Comment: "The problem here is that the Ret type of the UnaryPredicate must be the same as the type resulting from dereferencing the OutputIter." Thats not correct. `Ret` must not be the same type, but it must be possible to assign it to an element in the output range (ie `*it = some_ret_object;` must be ok)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am trying to implement `optional_back_inserter` now with the corresponding methods to do that...

Comment: I think all you need is a custom assignment operator for `ProjInfo`. Though, I'd need some time to write up a smaller example. Maybe you can try to simplify the code? The essential part seems to be the `std::optional` return, while the `regex` stuff could be removed I think

Comment: i dont understand the last code snippet. You are passing 2 callables to `std::transform`, but only 2 iterators?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number custom assignment operator makes sence if project info supports invalid state. It will still result in 1 to 1 resulting range and does not differ from returning `std::optional` which does not correspond the functions API - the function returns a vector of valid objects

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I stated in the comment that it is just an example to designate the behavior I need from a back_inserter - to ignore `nullopt`. It will not compile since it is not an iterator but a callable lambda

Comment: We have [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) but not `std::transform_if` (which would do the regex twice).

Comment: With ranges, you can `transform` into `regex_match`, then `filter` and finally `transform` into your output.

Comment: @Jarod42 the example with regex is not good as I have come to realize, since with `regex_iterator` every match in the UnaryPredicate is valid

Comment: BTW, a simple loop might do the job.

Comment: @Jarod42 this is true. But there's a difference between using a hand-made loop and customization of a standard function's behavior. When you customize you write *only the part that matters*, reusing other functionality. It is similar in the difference between using a loop and a range-based loop. The question is about customization, not about a particular problem that I posted as an example

Comment: You could have written the loop in the question (so intent would have been clearer ;-)).

Comment: I suppose you could have an iterator adaptor wrapping the `back_inserter` which advances its nested iterator only on a valid value, if you really insist on using `std::transform`. But `std::transform` is just a poor choice since from its point of view, the distance in input is always the distance in output.

Comment: @aschepler I've posted an answer with the wrapper

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use `std::transform`, use a similar algorithm

```
template< class InputIt,
          class OutputIt,
          class UnaryOperation >
OutputIt transform_if( InputIt first1,
                       InputIt last1,
                       OutputIt d_first, 
                       UnaryOperation unary_op )
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        if(auto v = unary_op(*first1++)) {
            *d_first++ = *std::move(v);
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Comment: There are various ways of doing things *by hand*, but the question is about the concept of Customisation of `std::transform` behaviour.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik: unaryOperation customization won't be able to filter. The other way would be the outputIterator (But I bet, if possible, than it would require to construct an "Null" `ProjInfo` and be really more verbose than presented solution)...

Comment: @Jarod42 I know, I customize the outout iterator. Read my answer with the wrapper

Comment: I tend to agree with your point if `transform` by it's nature returns 1-to-1 output. In that case a new distinct function like `transform_if` is more meaningful and clean.

Answer (score 1):

So this wrapper compiles. [Example.](https://godbolt.org/z/zE87dPYor)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail
{
    template <typename ContainerT>
    class optional_back_inserter
    {
    public:
        using container_type = ContainerT;
        using value_type = typename container_type::value_type;

        constexpr explicit optional_back_inserter(container_type &container)
            : backInserter_(container)
        {}

        optional_back_inserter& operator=(std::optional<value_type> value)
        {
            if (value)
                backInserter_ = std::move(*value);
            return *this;
        }

        /**
         * no-op
         * @return
         */
        constexpr optional_back_inserter& operator*()
        {
            return *this;
        }

        /**
         * no-op
         * @return
         */
        constexpr optional_back_inserter& operator++()
        {
            return *this;
        }


        /**
         * no-op
         * @return
         */
        constexpr optional_back_inserter operator++(int)
        {
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        std::back_insert_iterator<container_type> backInserter_;
    };
}

template <typename ContainerT>
constexpr auto optional_back_inserter(ContainerT &container)
{
    return detail::optional_back_inserter<ContainerT>(container);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
    std::vector<int> output{};

    std::transform(vec.cbegin(), 
    vec.cend(),
    optional_back_inserter(output),
    [](int i) -> std::optional<int>
    {
        if (i % 2)
            return {i};

        return std::nullopt;
    });

    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << output.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

This is "more verbose" but is more about separation of responcibilities. By customizing only the `outputIterator`'s behavior I remove the necessity of messing with the transformation logic by itself. It is SOLID-friendly, since  I don't need to modify the general logic, rather I can provide a customisation object in any other part of the code.

Comment: I'd be tempted to `std::move(value)` in the assignment

Comment: @Caleth acknowledged

Answer (score 1):

I am hesitating to put an answer in because I am not sure what exactly what you are asking but here is my attempt to answer: How do you transform between a type and it's optional type using `std::transform`?  If I have that wrong, let me know and I will delete the answer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> iv{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
  std::vector<std::optional<int>> oiv;
  std::transform(iv.begin(), iv.end(), std::back_inserter(oiv),
                 [](int i) -> std::optional<int> { return i % 2 == 0 ? std::optional<int>(i) : std::nullopt; });


  for (auto oi: oiv) {
    std::cout << ' ' << oi.has_value();
  }


  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Another possibility is to use ranges with pipes or functionally.

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto const ints = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  auto even = [](int i) { return 0 == i % 2; };
  auto to_option = [](int i) { return std::optional(i); };

  // "pipe" syntax of composing the views:
  for (std::optional<int> i: ints | std::views::filter(even) | std::views::transform(to_option)) {
    std::cout << i.value() << ' ';
  }

  std::cout << '\n';

  // a traditional "functional" composing syntax:
  for (std::optional<int> i: std::views::transform(std::views::filter(ints, even), to_option)) {
    std::cout << i.value() << ' ';
  }
}
```

SOLID principals are not really in play here since the STL is largely functional but one of the SOLID principals is the `single-responsibility principle` and by coupling two responsibilities into one function you are clearly breaking it.

Comment: the requirement is to "filter out" objects with invalid state and get a range of valid objects. I have mentioned in the question that one could get a range of optionals as an output and then filter the invalid objects. But thar will double the allocation overhead and will make copies, since optional is another type.

Comment: `oiv` and `iv` will have the same size. The requirement is for `oiv` to be less or equal and to store the valid objects of transformed type

Comment: I suggest you leave your answer anyway, since it helps to understand the concept better

Comment: Respectfully, transform is probably the wrong tool.  Transform should always take one thing and convert it to another thing in a 1-1 ratio.  Perhaps one of the new range functions might be better applied and less likely to generate confusion.  I am thinking `std::ranges::remove_copy_if`

Comment: the problem is with additional redundant copying and separation of responcibilities. For example I have a function that transforms input `A` to output `B` and throws if input is invalid (which is uncommon but recoverable. It is a runtime error). If I separate it to *validate* and *transform*, I will have to traverse 2 times -> filter then transform. Then I **eventually** would like to make a *facade* to combine this two functions, because they are inseparable within the business logic. I might agree that `transform` is not a proper name, but using it results in 2 operations in 1 go

Comment: Perhaps the pipe operator in ranges will help?  It allows piping one result at a time through a chain of functions.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges